# NoMethodError: undefined method for String with custom module in Hanami

Tags: ruby, hanami

I am using Hanami and I created a custom module in **/lib/supports/utils.rb**. I'm requiring all the files located **/lib/supports** in **/lib/myapp** that it's like the following:

```
require 'hanami/model'
require 'hanami/mailer'

Dir["#{__dir__}/myapp/**/*.rb"].each { |file| require_relative file }
Dir["#{__dir__}/supports/**/*.rb"].each { |file| require_relative file }

Hanami::Model.configure do

# and so on
```

In **/lib/supports/utils.rb**, I have:

```
# using the gem 'slugify'
require 'slugify'

module MyModule
  module Utils
    module Slug
      def slug_it(random = false)
        if random
          slugify + '-' + SecureRandom.hex(10).to_s
        else
          slugify
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to include **MyModule::Utils::Slug** in a repository but it always returns *NoMethodError: undefined method `slug_it' for "string":String*. An example:

```
class EventRepository
  include Hanami::Repository
  include MyModule::Utils::Slug

  def self.create_or_update(attrs)
    found = find(attrs.id)
    attrs = event_attributes(attrs)

    if found
      unless found.slug.include? attrs[:name].slug_it
        attrs[:slug] = attrs[:name].slug_it(true)
      end

      found.update(attrs)
      update found
    else
      attrs[:slug] = attrs[:name].slug_it(true)
      create Event.new(attrs)
    end
  end
end
```

It only works if I add at the bottom of **/lib/supports/utils.rb**:

```
class String
  include MyModule::Utils::Slug
end
```

I would like to always include the module like **`include Hanami::Repository`** in EventRepository.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include `MyModule::Utils::Slug` into `EventRepository`, the methods defined in the included module are available on an instance of `EventRepository` not on `String`. If you want to use the module as-is, you need to include it on `String`. If you don't want to include it on the global class you could do

```
module MyModule
  module Utils
    module Slug
      def slug_it(string, random = false)
        if random
          string.slugify + '-' + SecureRandom.hex(10).to_s
        else
          string.slugify
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then modify the slug creation to pass the string you want to `slugify`

```
unless found.slug.include? slug_it(attrs[:name])
  attrs[:slug] = slug_it(attrs[:name], true)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, @LukasEklund! Your answer really helped me. I also needed to change the order of requirement between Dir["#{__dir__}/myapp/**/*.rb"].each and Dir["#{__dir__}/supports/**/*.rb"].each and to extend the MyModule in EventRepository class.

Answer (score 0):

You could try somethong like it, also:

https://gist.github.com/rafaels88/5529b3863c699b1cd4d20265c32d4a21

```
# lib/your_app/ext/sluggable.rb

module Sluggable
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def sluggable(field)
      @field = field
    end

    def field
      @field
    end
  end

  def slug
    send(self.class.field).slugify
  end
end

# USAGE
#
# class MyEntity
#  include Hanami::Entity
#  include Sluggable

#  attributes :name, :slug, :other_field, :yet_another_field
#  sluggable :name
# end
#
# Do not forget to create :slug field in database and mapping it to its entity
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do that is:

```
require 'slugify'

module MyModule
  module Utils
    module Slug
      def self.slug_it(string, random = false) # Please note `self` and `string`
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
MyModule::Utils::Slug.slug_it(attrs[:name], true)
```